# Adobe Flex image scaling quality

Tags: apache-flex, image, scale

I have an image viewer I wrote in Flex that scales the size of the image you're currently viewing based on the size of the browser.  This is what the tag looks like:

```
<mx:Image id="img"
    maintainAspectRatio="true"
    source="{horizontalList.selectedItem.image}-large.jpg"
    height="100%"
    horizontalCenter="0"
    horizontalAlign="center"
    top="5" 
    width="{horizontalList.width}"
    updateComplete="onImageChange()"
    click="onImgClick()"
    />
```

The original image size is always larger than the area of the browser, and unfortunately, Flex doesn't appear to be doing a very good job of downscaling the image.  In fact, HTML in IE does a much better job if I use it's image tag.  Is there a "quality" setting for scaling in Flex that I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

See this: [Smoothing resized distorted images in flex](http://web.archive.org/web/20130606093949/http://askmeflash.com/article/4/smoothing-resized-distorted-images-in-flex)

Answer (score 1):

Learn about the [Flash Smoothing Issue](http://npacemo.com/wordpress/2009/07/31/flash-smoothing-issue/) I discovered few years ago and I blogged about. Basically, images that have an odd dimension(s) fail to be smoothed.

To fix this issue use the following snippet:

```
var smoothBitmapData : BitmapData = new BitmapData(
    loadedBitmap.width + (loadedBitmap.width % 2),
    loadedBitmap.height + (loadedBitmap.height % 2),
    true, 0x00FF0000);
smoothBitmapData.draw(loadedBitmap, null, null, null, null, true);

smoothBitmap = new Bitmap(smoothBitmapData, PixelSnapping.NEVER, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a spot of bother with Flex 3 -- using an image in a list control. You have to be very careful to get the scaling right.

Why not try playing around with different combinations of `scaleContent` and `maintainAspectRatio` properties of `Image` controls?

Here's a tutorial on [scaling](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=controls_16.html) Images.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  My image control isn't inside a list control.  It's just using a separate list control as a reference to size itself.  I read the tutorial you linked, but it didn't really talk about image quality.  My basic question is: How do you control quality when downscaling an image?  By default, Flex seems to have a lot of aliasing problems when shrinking the image.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to set the width and height of the  control to the dimensions of the image and set the scaleContent property to true

Answer (score 0):

set scaleContent property to true